# Android scrollview eating up added layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

I have a layout something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:background="#ff303f"
    android:id="@+id/layout">
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/picture"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancel"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/picture"
        android:background="@drawable/cross_out"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I inflate it using the usual layout inflator service, set up some functionality to the button and an image to the imageview (all images are of same size and aspect ratio).

After that, I add this view to my fragment's layout which is nothing but a ScrollView which is a parent, it has a child linear layout that I call 'map' and simply add it to the map.

Expected : The added layouts should get added properly and I can scroll through it. Actual : If more than 2 are added, the first one gets eaten up. I can see it half or sometimes it is completely eaten up. :\

Any idea whats going on here? Thanks a lot for your time.

EDIT: Here's the layout file I add the inflated layout into:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#f6ff45">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#43ff44"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I also forgot to mention that after adding 3 or more of these layouts, I realized there's unnecessary empty space in the end. :\

Comment: Can you provide the code where you actually add the views? And a ListView may be more efficient if you are adding many of the same views to the ScrollView.

Comment: Need to see how you add the views in code.

Answer (score 0):

try to define scrollView from Java code like

```
//Initialize the TextView for vertical scrolling
    output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    output.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

Comment: Its a layout that I inflate. Should I be finding each individual view inside that layout and setMovementMethod to them?

Comment: I think u misunderstood my question, There is no textview in this. The layouts I add (which is a combination of imageview and buttons), start going above the scroll view, like the scrollview kinda eats it up.

Comment: oh sorry.but you can try to set movement method to them yes.let me know if it works

Comment: Nope, there is no such method for ImageViews and Buttons or layouts. Its only for a textview